# Logback - Layout & Pattern in logback.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I am using logback with slf4j for logging in Spring Boot application. I have created a custom layout class because all log statements are to be wrapped as a json. I have configured the logback-spring.xml as show below to take the custom layout. It works!

Issue is I am unable to apply the pattern. Only either the layout works (or) the pattern. What I want is always on log, go to layout class and then apply the pattern before logging.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${user.home}/logs/sample.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/logs/sample_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- how many days to keep the files -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="com.test.test.payment.core.logging.SampleLogLayout" >
        </layout>
    </encoder>
    *<!-- <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>{"@timestamp": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}", "priority": "%p", "application": "payment",
            "class": "%C", "file": "%F:%L", "payload": %m }%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>-->*
</appender>
```

Here's the `SampleLogLayout` class:

```
public class SampleLogLayout extends LayoutBase<LoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    public String doLayout(LoggingEvent event) {

        String renderedMessage = event.getMessage();

        if (!isJson(renderedMessage)) {
            Throwable throwable = null;

            if (event.getLevel().equals(Level.ERROR) || event.getLevel().equals(Level.WARN)) {

            final IThrowableProxy throwableProxy = event.getThrowableProxy();
            if ((throwableProxy != null) && (throwableProxy instanceof ThrowableProxy)) {
                ThrowableProxy proxy = (ThrowableProxy) throwableProxy;
                throwable = proxy.getThrowable();
            }
            String message = LogErrorMessage.create(CommonCoreErrors.GENERIC_ERROR)
                    .message(renderedMessage).exception(throwable).build();

            return message;
        } else {
                return LogMessage.create(renderedMessage).build();
        }

        }
        return renderedMessage;
    }

    private boolean isJson(String msg) {
        if (null == msg) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return msg.startsWith("{") && msg.endsWith("}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see this class too: `com.test.test.payment.core.logging.SampleLogLayout`

Comment: Yep, have added my SampleLogLayout class. Basically LogErrorMessage.create() & LogMessage.create() convert the messages into JSON

Comment: Ok, that's useful. Still not clear to me what the issue is though. Are you saying that you would like `SampleLogLayout` to emit the `renderedMessage` with a pattern? Maybe adding (1) an example log invocation (so that we can see what a `renderedMessage` looks like) and (2) the desired output would help clarify things.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - we want the renderedMessage to be passed to a pattern.

Comment: Actual result with Layout is as follows,
{
  "logType": "EXCEPTION",
  "message": "testing",
  "errorDetails": {
    "errorCode": "COMMON_600",
    "errorDescription": "Generic Error"
  }
}

Comment: Expected result is as follows,
  "@timestamp": "2017-10-03 16:15:08.185",
  "priority": "ERROR",
  "application": "payment",
  "class": "com.test.LoggingInterceptor",
  "file": "LoggingInterceptor.java:36",
  "payload": {
  "logType": "EXCEPTION",
  "message": "testing",
  "errorDetails": {
    "errorCode": "COMMON_600",
    "errorDescription": "Generic Error"
  }
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I started to reproduce this in order to provide a complete solution but the absence of `LogMessage` and `LogErrorMessage` made that a bit tricky.

However, it looks to me like you just want to log in JSON format, not just the message but also the metadata such as `timestamp`, `priority` etc.

This can be achieved by using the `JsonLayout`. Here's an example of the layout configuration:

```
<layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
    <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
        <prettyPrint>false</prettyPrint>
    </jsonFormatter>
    <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
    <appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
    <includeContextName>false</includeContextName>
</layout>
```

With that configuration the following log invocation ...

```
logger.info("{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}");
```

... will emit:

```
{"timestamp":"2017-10-05 10:51:34.610","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"com.stackoverflow.logback.LogbackTest","message":"{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"}
```

You can include MDC too, for example ...

```
MDC.put("application", "payment");
logger.info("{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}");
```

... will emit:

```
{"timestamp":"2017-10-05 10:52:56.088","level":"INFO","thread":"main","mdc":{"application":"payment"},"logger":"com.stackoverflow.logback.LogbackTest","message":"{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"}
```

That's quite close to your desired output and `JsonLayout` is extensible so you could ...

- Override `toJsonMap()` to change names of the keys e.g. replace `timestamp` with `@timestamp`, replace `message` with `payload`
- Implement `addCustomDataToJsonMap()` to add other key:value pairs to the log event

So, I think you could achieve your desired output using the pre-existing `JsonLayout` rather than writing your own.

More details on Logback JSON extensions [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-contrib/wiki/JSON).

The Maven coordinates are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-json-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks glitch! It works. I tried with <conversionRule conversionWord="jsonMsg" converterClass="com.test.test.payment.core.logging.JsonFormatLogConverter"/> and that was also working with JsonFormatLogConverter extending ClassicConverter. I ll go with your solution. Thanks

Comment: @glytching once I override the addCustomDataToJsonMap() method how can I use that to set custom flields: